# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type int& from an rvalue of type int

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, reference

In the code below, when I take `idx` and `sum` as reference, it shows the given error. It works fine if I take `idx` and `sum` without reference. Why?

```
void func(int &idx, int &sum, vector<int> &arr, int N, vector<int> &res)
{   
    if(idx == N)
    {
        res.push_back(sum);
        return;
    }
    // pick the element
    func(idx + 1, sum+arr[idx], arr, N, res);
    
    // not pick the element
    func(idx + 1, sum, arr, N, res);
}

vector<int> subsetSums(vector<int> arr, int N)
{
    // Write Your Code here
    int idx = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    vector<int> res;
    func(idx, sum, arr, N, res);
    sort(res.begin(), res.end());
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`idx + 1` is a temporary, it does not have an address so it cannot be bound to a reference. Same goes for `sum+arr[idx]`.

It might be a good idea to use `const` for input-only parameters. Because `const int&` can bind to temporaries. Although, there is no reason to pass integral types by constant references, passing by value is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You call `func` recursively and you pass `idx + 1` as a first parameter, but `idx + 1` cannot be an lvalue reference, only an rvalue because it is a temporary value.

Comment: "*`idx + 1` cannot be an lvalue reference*" - more accurately, it can't bind to a **non-const** lvalue reference.  It *can* bind to a **const** lvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you for modifications and for completing my answer! :) @Remy